# Issue with "Contenful" API: Storing images is randomly failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, contentful, contentful-management

we are using the **Contentful** API with Angular 1.

When we try to store an image (file size does not matter) the Contentful API randomly throws an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Asset is taking longer then expected to process.
```

As it is working fine most of the time I think there might not be an issue with our code. Maybe someone of you guys experienced the same issue and could solve it?

That's our factory:

```
ContentFulFactory.createAssetFromFiles()
.then((space) => {
    space.createAsset({
        fields: {
            title: {
                'en': $scope.file.title
            },
            file: {
                'en': {
                    contentType: $scope.file.image.type,
                    fileName: $scope.file.image.$ngfName,
                    upload: data.data.url
                }
            }
        }
    })
        .then((asset) => {
            /**
             * Processing asset
             */
            console.log('processing...', asset);
            return asset.processForLocale('en', { processingCheckWait: 100, processingCheckRetries: 20 });
        })
        .then((asset) => {
            /**
             * Publishing asset
             */
            console.log('publishing...', asset);
            return asset.publish();
        })
        .then((asset) => {
            console.log(asset);
            $scope.isProgress = false;
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        })
});
```

Thanks in advance!